# Where in Vue do I add some code to change the font size dynamically based on a class?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In Vue I have a card set up that can take a max char of 100 and I want to change the font size depending on the number of charters in the card to make the most of the space.

```
      <v-card
        flex
      >
        <v-card-text
          v-text="content"
        />
      </v-card>
```

In JS I want to dynamically change .card-text to change depending on the length of text in the container. Where and how in Vue do I add this?

```
fontSize = Math.min(Math.max(parseInt(node.content.length/5), 12), 20)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<template>
    <v-card flex @click="editNode(node)">
        <v-card-text text-no-wrap class="card-text" v-model="nodeContent"/>
    </v-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            nodeContent : '',
            textSize : '0px'
        }
    }, 
    watch:{
        nodeContent(val, oldVal){
            this.textSize = Math.min(Math.max(parseInt(val.length/5), 12), 20).toString() + 'px';
            console.log(this.textSize);
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style>
    .card-text{
        font-size: v-bind('textSize');
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Sorry not what I am looking for. I just what to know where I add my function

Comment: yea u could add whatever logic you want in the watcher

Comment: here what i did was set the font size as the length the text... you could change that to what you have above

Comment: i have edited can you check?

Comment: How to I get this to work for Vue2?